# Which bond is stronger: N=O or C=N?

Tags: organic-chemistry

Which bond is stronger?  N=O or C=N?
I tried comparing it using electronegativity difference. But, I don't know if that is the correct method. Can anyone explain it?

Comment: Electronegativity difference has hardly anything to do with bond strength.

Comment: Electronegativity differences does affect the energy of the valence orbitals involved in making the bonds (i.e. the higher the electronegativity of the element, the lower the energy of the valence orbitals). Thus, it is indeed an important consideration. However, I think the effect is only minor. More important considerations would be bond order and also type of hybridisation of the orbitals used.

Answer (score 2):

The $\ce{C=N}$ bond has a dissociation energy of $\pu{615kJ/mol}$, while $\ce{N=O}$ has an energy of $\pu{607kJ/mol}$. The difference isn't much, so its difficult trying to comparing the energies without being given the exact values.

**References:**

Yoder, Claude. “Wired Chemist.” Common Bond Energies (D, www.wiredchemist.com/chemistry/data/bond_energies_lengths.html.

Comment: Is there any theoretical way to guess bond energies?

Comment: I would think the $\alpha$-effect would make the $\ce{N=O}$ bond weaker. Not sure if this is the primary factor though.